# Python Tkinter generating a random 'password' for each entry in a list box?

Tags: python, arrays, listbox, tkinter

I am trying to create a password generator that creates a new password for each individual line in a listbox, i have a listbox populated with names, im trying to get a loop that will count how many names there are in the list and for each one creat a password. i have the password generator im just trying to figure out how the loop would look.

here is what i have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
import os, random, string

appWin = Tk() #the main application window
lstBoxArray = [] #an atrray to hold all the listboxes

def passWord():
    length = 8
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
    psword = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
    print(psword)
    #this section generates a random 'code' which is the password
    #at the moment it is still a stub hence the print command at the end.

stdName = Listbox(frm) #listbox populated by names
stdUserName = Listbox(frm) #listbox where a login username is shown
stdPass = Listbox(frm) #listbox where the passwords will be placed
lstBoxArray = [stdName, stdUserName, stdPass]

scrBar.config(command=setlstBoxYview)          ##
stdName.config(yscrollcommand=scrBar.set)
stdUserName.config(yscrollcommand=scrBar.set)
stdPass.config(yscrollcommand=scrBar.set)
                                              # these are just configuring the listboxs
stdName.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='NS')
stdUserName.grid(column=4,row=0,sticky='NS')
stdPass.grid(column=5,row=0,sticky='NS')
scrBar.grid(column=6,row=0,sticky='NS')
frm.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)                  ##
```

so basically my stdName listbox is populated with about 28 names and its the same with the stdUserName listbox.
i wanted to make a loop that would count how many names there were and for each one create a password for it.

something like this.

```
def passGen():
    for i in range(stdName.size()): #this counts how many names there are
        'until there is the same number of pswords as there are i'
        loop the passWord and 
        stdPass.insert(END, passWord) each time it loops
        stop when stdPass == stdName
```

^^this obviously isnt code but it is what i'm trying to get^^
and my goal is to then link passGen to a button.
I havent included my all my code as it isnt really releavent but help with this would be much appreciated.

p.s. sorry if there are any spelling mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: People who camelcase "password" (or "username") hurt my eyes.

Comment: Providing an example of what you have already tried is definitely a good think (and is recognised as good will by the community). That said you could try a little harder to restrict your example to exhibit your issue, as well as to provide a "compilable" example (for instance, here `frm` and `scrBar` are both irrelevant and undeclared...).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you edit the last line of `passWord` to return the password (instead of print it),
`passGen` would be as simple as:

```
def passGen():
     for i in range(stdName.size()):
        stdPass.insert(END, passWord())
```

Creating the same number of password than the count of names is enough to guarantee you will have the same count.

If you think of it as filling the password column to match the name column count, a while loop could better reflect your intent:

```
def passGen():
    while stdPass.size() < stdName.size():
        stdPass.insert(END, passWord())
```